# Route protection from multiple referrer - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to protect a `route` if not accessed from a particular page and have the below piece of code that doesn't work as expected;

```
$referer = Request::header('referer');

if ($referer != "http://www.xxx.co.uk/login" || $referer != "http://www.xxx.co.uk/signup") {
    return redirect()->route('/');
}
```

I'm doing something wrong with my `if` statement because the below works;

```
$referer = Request::header('referer');

if ($referer != "http://www.xxx.co.uk/login") {
    return redirect()->route('/');
}
```

The difference being that I removed the `or` part.
But I need it protected if not accessed from both `paths`.
Also adding another `else if` statement breaks it aswell

Comment: Must be different from both, or just one? because an "AND" would be the right option there (T v F = T)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use **&&** operator instead of **||**.

In your case, using ||, when a single condition is falsy, the other is certain truthy, so your statement will be always executed.

Answer (score 0):

In general boolean logic:

```
(!A) || (!B) === !(A && B)
```

so your first if condition is actually:

```
!($referer == "http://www.xxx.co.uk/login" && $referer == "http://www.xxx.co.uk/signup")
```

Which is always true, as the referer can't match both urls at the same time. Fix your logic accordingly